# How to resize dw_height

Tags: height, powerbuilder, autoresize, datawindow, row-height

[image]Good evening teachers, please help and enlighten me, I have 2 DWs to use as DW menus, what I ask is how to make the lower dw_height = the height of the number of rows that appear, (the number of these rows changes according to user access), then the upper dw_ mah = this height -dw_ Bawah.height, please help, thank you very much in advance

Comment: Good evening PB seniors, please help, I have 2 datawindows that I use for the left side menu, dw_down and dw_up, dw_down retrieves dw_up, what I'm asking is, how do I make this dw_down height = the height of the number of rows that appear, the number of rows changes according to user access, and height dw_up is window height-height dw_down, please help, Thanks in advance, my respect, Herman

Answer (score 0):

When you create the datawindow object you designate the height of the detail band as part of the design.  This is where the rows of data are displayed.  So if that height is 80 and you want the control on the form to 'adjust' in size when 3 rows are retrieved you would start with a height of 240 (3 x 80). Now if you have a header band or some other stuff in the datawindow you will also have to account for that as well.